# Keyboard 3rd layer wrong after update

Tags: 22.04, keyboard-layout

OK here we go again... we're maintainimg a pure Ubuntu machine for reference purposes w/ German setup:

```
~ $ inxi -Fz
System: Kernel: 5.15.0-58-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
```

After recent update to latest versions (apt-get dist-upgrade) the 3rd layer of the keyboard is mixed up in all applications, including terminal, browsers and word processors.

`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` shows correct settings (Generic 105/German...) with right-Alt (AltGr) as access to 3rd layer.

Holding AltGr and typing keys on first row (1, 2, 3, ...) should produce the sequence `¹²³¼½¬{[]}\` but actually produces `¹²³$‰↑&∞←→—`

Frankly, I'm at loss. Any hint highly welcome. -mgw

Edit: Added screenshot from settings for wrong keyboard layout
[image]

Edit:

```
~$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
[('xkb', 'de')]
```

Comment: The unexpected output indicates that the effective keyboard layout is something else but the basic German one.

Comment: Yes, but: Why? No changes in any settings whatsoever!

Comment: Removed existing and added Deutsch - Deutschland in settings - no change. The keyboard layout is erroneous (unless a have blind spot due to Lenovo)

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/KB_Germany.svg 105 German standard layout.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the output of this terminal command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`

Comment: Edited question per request

Comment: Only the basic German layout. I'm also confused. One long shot would be to reinstall the package which provides the layouts: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`

Comment: Did as suggest and reboot: unfortunately no change...